# How to check from a Spotify App when a playlist is removed

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, playlist

I'm finding a way to check when a playlist is removed inside a Spotify app.
In the current [API Docs](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/c49e02a392.html), there's no REMOVE event, so suppose to have this use case

- The user add a playlist from a list of tracks in the app
- The app stores somewhere the playlist's name (localStorage by example)
- The user remove the app from the Spotify SideBar
- The user goes back to the app, and try to add the playlist again from the same list of tracks;
- Since there's no REMOVE event binded to the playlist, the app can't know if the playlist was removed, so

  - If it checks the playlist in the localStorage, now new playlist will
    be added (bug);
  - If no further check is done, the same playlist will be added twice;

Any way to handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there is no REMOVE event. There is still however the property called subscribed that will tell you if a playlist is subscribed or not.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/c49e02a392.html

If you check that just before rendering and/or when you are about to add a playlist, you could make a UI that will show you if a playlist has been added or not and also make sure you don't add it twice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a playlist removed event you can subscribe to in the windows/mobile API.  Check out this link for more details:

[playlist_removed](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/structsp__playlistcontainer__callbacks.html#ad49b8c0f44f6c05e4ab3562b023f0928)

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for the confusion, this is related to the Spotify JavaScript SDK.